# Is it possible to display another text within a source viewer

Tags: java, jface

I would like to change the displayed text in a source viewer.

The Document content would be `The @ref{001} is present.` and it should be displayed as "The *label of 001* is present." in the source viewer.

While editing, backspace at the and or delete at the begining of "*label of 001*" should remove the whole block.

Does someone know how to do that? Or another component to do the same?

Comment: Let me get this right: you want your Document content to be different than the one displayed when inspected in your source?

Comment: Yes, something like a wysiwyg editor with few replacement patterns

Comment: I doubt there is such an editor and if it existed it would cause more troubles: imagine if the actual text was indeed "The label of 001 is present." how the 2 texts would be distinguished?

Comment: Using a different formatting, that's why I set the label in italic.